# Three normals of a parabola with tangent angles $a$, $b$, $c$ meet at a point with angle $d$. Prove $d=a+b+c-\pi$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The polar equation of a parabola is given by

$$r=a \ {\csc^2 \dfrac {\theta} {2}}$$

If the normals at three points on the parabola
whose vectorial angle are $a,b,c,$ meet at a point whose vectorial angle is $d,$ prove that

$$d=a+b+c-\pi$$

I tried doing this by polar equations and using the general equations of normals whose vectorial angles are given.

It is a challenge for me to solve it.
I would appreciate a eloborate proof.

Comment: Someone pls do it

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it are welcome

Comment: Comments don't call attention to a problem, so you're really just talking to yourself. :) ... If you want more attention, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3495326/edit) to improve its quality. In particular, add some details about exactly what you've tried. As suggested in comments to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3487808/409), Math.SE doesn't exist to do your homework for you. It also doesn't always provide answers to fit your personal schedule. Patience is advised.

Comment: I notice that you reversed someone's edit that formatted the equation as $$r = \frac{a\csc^2(\theta)}{2}$$ losing a square in the process. Should the equation be $$r = a\csc^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$ instead? (This is a proper form for a parabola equation.)

Comment: What do you mean by vectorial angle? The angle made by the line joining a point and the origin with the positive x-axis?

Comment: Yes Mr Blue the edit I made was the correct one

Comment: Vectorial angle refers to the angle between polar axis and radius vector

Comment: I haven't been able to do this problem for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the equation of the parabola $r=a \ {\csc^2 \dfrac {\theta} {2}}$ in the Cartesian coordinates

$$y^2= 4t(x+t)\tag 1$$

(Note the parameter $t$, instead of $a$, is used to avoid confusion with the angle $a$.)

The tangent of the normal at any point $(x,y)$ on the parabola is  $\tan\theta=-\frac{y}{2t}$. Assume that the three normals meet at the point $(p,q)$. The following equation can be established by matching their tangents,

$$\frac{q-y}{p-x}=-\frac{y}{2t}\tag 2$$

Eliminate $x$ from (1) and (2) to get

$$y^3-4t(p-t)y-8t^2q=0\tag 3$$

Note that the cubic equation (3) does admit three normals, corresponding to the tangent angles $a$, $b$ and $c$. Then, according to the Vieta's formulas,

$$y_a \>y_b\>y_c = 8t^2q$$
$$y_a + y_b +y_c = 0$$
$$y_a \>y_b+y_b\>y_c + y_c\>y_a= -4t(p-t)q$$
and the tangents of the three normals are respectively,

$$\tan a  =-\frac{y_a}{2t},\>\>\>\>\>\tan b  =-\frac{y_b}{2t},\>\>\>\>\>\tan c  =-\frac{y_c}{2t}$$

Use above results to evaluate

$$\tan (a+b+c) 
= \frac{\tan a + \tan b +\tan c - \tan a \tan b\tan c}{1-(\tan a \tan b+\tan b\tan c + \tan c\tan a)}$$
$$= \frac{-\frac1{2t}(y_a + y_b +y_c) +\frac1{8t^3}y_a y_by_c }{1-\frac1{4t^2}(y_a y_b+y_by_c + y_cy_a)}
= \frac pq = \tan d$$

which leads to either $d=a + b+ c$, or $d+\pi=a + b+ c$. To determine the valid expression, check the special case of $(p,q)$ on the $x$-axis, where we know $a+b=\pi$ and $c=d = 0$. Thus,

$$d = a + b+ c-\pi$$